# CSS Stylesheets on Wordpress Production server not loading

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I'm running into a strange problem, with my wordpress site.  I'm using a child theme of wp-bootstrap.  When I upload the site to my shared host, it appears that wordpress is pulling the css from my local host.  In other words, the site loads on my local computer, however, on any other computer the stylesheets don't work and the page looks messed up.  If I look at the source, the address is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" >>href="http://**localhost**/wordpress/wp_content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/library/css/bootstrap.css?ver=1.0" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" >>href="http://**www.mydomain.com**/wordpress/wp_content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/library/css/bootstrap.css?ver=1.0" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Does anybody know what might be going on here and any possible fixes?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you dump the database straight from local to prod? It's probably got localhost as the site url?

Comment: Yeah I did.  Forgive me, but I'm kind of a wp noob.  Where would I go about changing this in the database structure?

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/ Specifically this part - `Step 5: Changing the Site URL`

Comment: Actually I figured it out.  Thanks for your help.  This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your styles.css file in the root directory.  My default css file looks like so:

```
/*
Theme Name: MDA
Theme URI: http://zachjanice.com
Description: A website using Bootstrap 3 built for the MDA of Kansas City
Author: Zach Janice
Author URI: http://zachjanice.com/
Version: 1.0
Tags: responsive, bootstrap
*/

@import url('css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('css/style.css');
```

You need the top information for the css file to register.  If your bootstrap/custom css file is in a folder called "css," Wordpress will pull those files for you without having to register each css file.

Here is a link to the codex that might help as well.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Hope this helps.